# GET or POST from express do not parse a "percent sign" request

Tags: node.js, express, parsing, escaping, node-modules

I am having difficulties in parsing an HTTP request that uses a "%26" instead of a "&" character.

Context: I am trying to receive an HTTP request made by an IP camera that has a limitation where it cannot send the '&' character, so I have to set it up using '%26' to separate parameters, so the camera is making a POST request like this:

http://192.168.45.4:8000/test?foo=me%26bar=them

To process this request on my server side, I have this simple function:

```
Broker.all("*", (req,res) => {
    console.log("foo=" + req.query.foo);
    console.log("bar=" + req.query.bar);

    console.log("Received a generic put request");
    res.send("Processed");
});
```

This code is working fine when I make a request using the '&' character.

This is the result to the request: http://192.168.45.4:8000/test?foo=me&bar=them

```
foo=me
bar=them
Received a generic put request
```

This is the result to the request: http://192.168.45.4:8000/test?foo=me%26bar=them

```
foo=me&bar=them
bar=undefined
Received a generic put request
```

I have been banging my head for the past... (ashamed)... nevermind how many hours, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I'm pretty sure this is easy, but I really couldn't find it on the forums, maybe because I wasn't able to search specifically for "%26" in the posts.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT after being solved

As suggested by GPack, I used his parser code, and it seems to be working. Just need to make sure to check beforehand if the Generic URL does have parameters or not.
I still believe there might be a more natural way to do this with express...

This is the new code with the parser which is working:

```
broker.all("*", (req,res) => {

    const list = req.originalUrl.split("?")[1].split("%26");
    const params = list.reduce((obj, str) => {
        const parts = str.split("=");
        obj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
        return obj;
    }, {});
    console.log(params); // { bar: "them", foo: "me" }
    
    console.log("foo=" + params.foo);
    console.log("bar=" + params.bar);

    console.log("Received a generic put request");
    res.send("I'm just a simple broker");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using decodeURI & decodeURIComponent but in vain.
So I wrote the parser myself:

```js
// The request object should be something like this (with other attributes)
const req = {
  originalUrl: "/test?foo=me%26bar=them"
}

// You may want to handle the case where a request doesn't have parameters
const list = req.originalUrl.split("?")[1].split("%26");
const params = list.reduce((obj, str) => {
  const parts = str.split("=");
  obj[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(params); // { bar: "them", foo: "me" }
```

Comment: Thank you! This does solve the issue, but I was trying to avoid this, where I assumed express or something else would be designed to handle this...

Comment: So... would you consider accepting my answer?

Comment: I have been trying to apply your parser function to my, and have found difficulties. I will edit my post with the difficulties.

Comment: You're doing `var list = req.query.foo;`, it should be `var list = req.query;`

Comment: If I use ```list = req.query;``` I get an "list.reduce is not a function" error.
If I use ```list = req.query.split("&");``` I get an "split is not a function" error.
If I use ```var list = req.query.split("%26");``` it works but I get this result: { '{"foo":"me&bar': 'them"}' }

Comment: My bad dude, I forgot req.query was an object and not a string. Then we need to use the original url and get everything that is after the `?`. Then we can split the string around %26 etc. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That fixed it, but I still have an error. I have updated my post with details

Comment: Is the line 63, the line where you do this: `const list = req.originalUrl.split("?")[1].split("%26");`? That means you're receiving a request without params

Comment: You are right... It was just the damn "fav.ico" that triggered it while I was testing thank you